# Trust a Clojure collection to be sorted

Tags: clojure

If I get a sorted list of objects from an external API, is there a way to put it in a sorted set without the overhead of re-sorting it? Something like:

```
=> (sorted? (assume-sorted [1 2 3]))
true
```

Comment: If it is already sorted the overhead should be nearly zero. Have you measured the times for sorted/unsorted inputs? I'd suggest doing it the simplest possible way then measuring the run time.

Comment: `sorted?` only checks if the coll instance implements `clojure.lang.Sorted` so you could fudge it with you own datastructure implmentation ? maybe ?

Comment: @birdspider Well, if it's between the overhead and reimplementing sorted sets from scratch, I'll take the overhead =)

Comment: @AlanThompson The unsorted sequence [is actually faster](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mvomi3ce02etkc4/sorted-set.png?dl=0)... Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: A 20% difference is not worth worrying about.

Comment: @AlanThompson What do you mean? The difference is small and that is precisely the problem. I would expect putting an already sorted collection into a sorted set to be 1000x faster that an unsorted one here, but it turned out 20% slower.

Answer (score 1):

Clojure uses a persistant Red/Black Tree data structure for sorted sets &  maps. When an inserted item makes the tree too unbalanced, the root & nodes of the tree are rearranged to keep itself "approximately" balanced.

What your measurement shows is that there is slightly more overhead in rebalancing a tree that only grows on the right (every new addition unbalances the tree further to the right) compared to a tree that grows in random locations (some insertions will randomly make the tree more balanced).

See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree
- https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentTreeMap.java

---

## Update

I just tried on my computer and get very different results than your test. This once again shows the folly of trying to optimize prematurely (especially if the change is less than 2x):

```
(def x (range 1000000))
(def y (doall (shuffle x)))

parse.core=> (time (doall (set x) nil))
"Elapsed time: 279.259531 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 291.31022 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 414.752484 msecs"

parse.core=> (time (doall (set y) nil))
"Elapsed time: 286.496324 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 284.95049 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 285.568222 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 301.55659 msecs"

parse.core=> (time (doall (into (sorted-set) x) nil))
"Elapsed time: 816.473169 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 775.025901 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 763.638447 msecs"

parse.core=> (time (doall (into (sorted-set) y) nil))
"Elapsed time: 1307.969889 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 1313.099123 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 1285.665797 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 1307.879676 msecs"
```

## The Moral of the Story

1. First make it right
2. If it is fast enough, move on to the next problem
3. If it needs to be faster, measure where the biggest bottleneck is
4. Decide if it's cheaper to just use more h/w at $0.03/hr or to spend human time on code changes (which will increase complexity & reduce maintainability etc).